# entity framework many to many multiple select

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have 3 tables for many to many relationship.

MailLists =>MailListInGroups<=MailGroups

And MailListInGroups table like below;

```
MLID    MGID

2          1

2          3

3          2

3          3

4          1

4          4

5          1

5          5

6          2

6          5

7          2

7          3
```

My MailGroups Table below;

```
MGID

1   Türkiye

2   İtalya

3   Çok İyi

4   İyi

5   Orta
```

And My MailLists Table below;

```
MLID

2   xxx@hotmail.com NULL    NULL

3   yyy@hotmail.com NULL    NULL

4   zzz@hotmail.com NULL    NULL

5   ppp@hotmail.com NULL    NULL

6   trp@deneme.com  NULL    NULL

7   zzz@hotmail.com NULL    NULL
```

I need fetch to MailGroupID just 2 and 3. And My action below;

for example `int[] ints= 2,3`

```
public ActionResult SelectGroup(int[] ints)
{
    var mails = new List<MailList>();
    var groups = ints.Select(item => _bb.MailGroups.Include("MailLists").Where(m => m.MailGroupID == item)).ToList();                      
}
```

Groups select all include MailGroupID's 2 and 3 rows.(MLID=2,3,6,7). But I need just 2 rows.(MLID=3,7) How can select just 2 MLID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public ActionResult SelectGroup(int[] ints)
{     
   var listToFilter = new HashSet<int>(ints);       
   var list = _bb.MailGroups.Where(m => listToFilter.Contains(m.ID))
                            .SelectMany(m => m.MailLists);
}
```

***Update :***

I think that u need to change your method to be like this :

```
public ActionResult SelectGroup(int[] mailGroupIds, int[] mailListIds)
{          
   var list = _bb.MailGroups.Where(m => mailGroupIds.Contains(m.ID))
                            .SelectMany(m => m.MailLists)
                            .Where(l => mailListIds.Contains(l.ID));
}
```

Comment: doesn't work. this code returned 5 MailList result. 2,3,3,6,7,7

Comment: Then you need to add new list for wanted MailLists ids to filter the result against it

Comment: Thanks for reply... How can I filter? This is very hard for me. Please could you send an example? Thanks

Comment: But I cant get maillistIds. Because this is select list and It have just mailgroupIds....

Comment: Absolutely perfect But I cant take a vote. My reputation is bad...:) But I follow on tweeter to you....